# Text sequence to integer with many integer classes in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am getting strings ex. "one hundred twenty three", or "nine hundred ninety nine", and encoding it into a sequence of word tokens of length 4 using the Keras text preprocessing tokenizer and using it as my input with 4 nodes, and having many integer classes as my output ex. 0 1 2 ... 1000 with 1001 output nodes with a tensorflow backend.

I'm using an embedding input layer and then a flatten layer and then a dense output layer with softmax activation to classify the input sequence to a number.

This approach works well for numbers from 0-1000 etc. but scaling up to 100,000 numbers with strings like "eighty seven thousand four hundred twenty three" proves to be a problem with very long training times as there's 100,000 output neurons.

Is there a better way to structure the NN for possibly millions of numbers without sacrificing efficiency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can formulate it as sequence prediction problem using RNN or regression problem with N digit output nodes.

Comment: I tried something like this initially but it didn't work out. I'll give it another try and report back

Comment: When I initially made the NN I had the text sequence as an input and another sequence containing the digits of the output number. It didn't work out because the loss never ended up quite converging and the accuracy wasn't very good. This time around I made the output an array with 10 columns and N rows where N is the number of maximum digits of the output number. The output layer had softmax activation so the highest number in the row had the index of the predicted digit. This approach ended up working very well for digits into the billions